# SQL Server: Bulk Insert to a Linked Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

I have a local database `myDB` and a server database `serverDB` that is linked to `myDB` as `[serverDB].serverDB.dbo`. I want to upload a 50,000-row table from a .csv file on my computer to the `serverDB`. I tried this:

```
bulk insert #temp from 'filename'
insert into [serverDB].serverDB.dbo.tablename select * from #temp
```

and it takes ages. I found out that the `insert into` creates connection for each row, so it looks like it's not an option in this case. Then I tried

```
bulk insert [serverDB].serverDB.dbo.tablename from 'filename'
```

and I get the error `Invalid object name 'tablename'` even thought this table exists in the `[serverDB].serverDB` database. Does anyone know how I can make SQL "see" the table `[serverDB].serverDB.dbo.tablename`?

Comment: Load the csv contents to your local database first, then tell the server to **pull** the data through the linked server (way faster than **pushing**). The linked server must be configured on the server for this though.

Comment: The server is the production server, I can't link my local DB to it just to upload this file. Is there a way to push the data through a one-way linked server? (I mean that the server is linked to myDB, but myDB isn't linked to the server)

Comment: Yes, you can still push the data, but it will take much longer. You might want to consider using a SSIS package. Please check this post https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46289/which-one-is-more-efficient-select-from-linked-server-or-insert-into-linked-ser

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458052/linked-server-insert-select-performance